# Is my MySQL SELECT statement correct?

Tags: mysql, select

```
SELECT c FROM TableBC WHERE TableBC.b=TableAB.b AND TableAB.a='917-890-59603'
```

I'm sorry, I can't check it right away but I need an answer.
All I want is to find c from TableBC.
TableAB has two columns a and b, TableBC has two columns b and c.
All values are unique at any row.

Will it find c that corresponds to a without errors?

Comment: I really don't understand why am I getting negative "-2" for my question. What's wrong with my question? I really appreciate if anybody explain me. Does it look stupid? Too simple? Or too odd? Thank you. Mitch, thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: Haradzieniec, mouse over the downvote arrow to the left of your question to see why people are downvoting this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your question's intent was to join via the '`b`' column:

```
SELECT c 
FROM TableBC tbc
INNER JOIN TableAB tab ON tbc.b = tab.b
WHERE tab.a = '917-890-59603'
```